# error: cannot read <a> property of 'undefined' but the 'undefined' object appears to be valid in another code segment

Tags: reactjs

I have a state 'raterNameList', which is an `array` of objects with different properties (rater1name, rater1score, rater2name, rater2score, ...)
when I called `this.state.raterNameList[0].rater1name`, I got the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '`rater1name`' of undefined", and if I put in the condition check for `this.state.raterNameList[0]!=null`, it appears that `raterNameList[0]` is null.
However, within the next code section, I called `this.state.raterNameList.map` and display rater1score for every item in the list, it can display the value for item `#0` just fine.
I am very new to react and don't know what I did wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../App.css'

class Consensus extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.state = {
        justLoaded:true,
        panelval: '',
        hr:'',
        raterNameList: [],     
        r1: '',
        r2:'',
        r3:'',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeHR = this.handleChangeHR.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeFinalScore = this.handleChangeFinalScore.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  getRaterList = () => {
    var fetchquery="./api/consensustable?panelName=" + this.state.panelval
    console.log ("Hello" + fetchquery)
    console.log ("mounted =" + this.state.justLoaded)
    fetch(fetchquery)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then (raterNameList =>{
         this.setState({raterNameList})
    })
  };

  getRaterName =()=>{
    if (this.state.raterNameList[0]!=null){
    this.setState({r1: this.state.raterNameList[0].rater1name});
    this.setState({r2: this.state.raterNameList[0].rater2name});
    this.setState({r3: this.state.raterNameList[0].rater3name}); 
    }
    else{
      this.setState({r1: "Rater1"});
      this.setState({r2: "Rater2"});
      this.setState({r3: "Rater3"}); 
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({panelval: event.target.value});
  }
  handleChangeHR(event) {
    this.setState({hr: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeFinalScore(event) {
    this.setState({finalScore: event.target.value});
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    console.log('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.panelval);
    this.setState({justLoaded: false});
    event.preventDefault();
    this.getRaterList();
    this.getRaterName();
   }
  handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }

render () {
  if (!this.state.justLoaded)
  {
    return(  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label> Consensus Panel Name: {this.state.panelval}  </label>  
        <table>
          <tbody >
            <tr>
            <table>
             <tbody>
                  <td className="matchsizing">Applicant Name</td>
                  <td className="scorebox">{this.state.r1}</td>
                  <td className="scorebox">{this.state.r2}</td>
                  <td className="scorebox">{this.state.r3}</td>
                  <td className="finalscorebox">Final Score</td>
                  <td className="finalscorebox">Advance?</td>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <table >
                  {this.state.raterNameList.map((ra, i)=>(  
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td className="matchsizing" >{i}: {ra.applicantname} </td> 
                          <td className="scorebox" >{ra.rater1score}</td>    
                          <td className="scorebox" >{ra.rater2score}</td>    
                          <td className="scorebox">{ra.rater3score}</td>   
                          <td className="scorebox">
                            <input type="text" name="finalScore"  value={ra.finalscore}  />
                            </td>   
                          <td className="scorebox">ra.advance</td>    
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan="6">
                            <textarea rows ="5" cols="136" className="textarea" placeholder="Enter details here..."></textarea>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    )    
                    )
                  }
                </table>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="9">
                      <label>Human Resources Representative: </label>
                      <input type="text" value={this.state.hr} onChange={this.handleChangeHR} />

                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </form>
    )
  }
  else
  {
    return(  
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label>Panel Name:    </label>  
      <input type="text" value={this.state.panelval} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <button type="button" value="get Panel" onClick={this.handleClick}> get Panel </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}}


export default Consensus;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../App.css";

class Consensus extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      justLoaded: true,
      panelval: "",
      hr: "",
      raterNameList: [],
      r1: "",
      r2: "",
      r3: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeHR = this.handleChangeHR.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeFinalScore = this.handleChangeFinalScore.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  getRaterList = cb => {
    var fetchquery = "./api/consensustable?panelName=" + this.state.panelval;
    console.log("Hello" + fetchquery);
    console.log("mounted =" + this.state.justLoaded);
    fetch(fetchquery)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(raterNameList => {
        this.setState({ raterNameList });
        cb(raterNameList);
      });
  };

  getRaterName = raterNameList => {
    if (raterNameList && raterNameList.length) {
      this.setState({
        r1: raterNameList[0].rater1name,
        r2: raterNameList[0].rater2name,
        r3: raterNameList[0].rater3name
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ r1: "Rater1", r2: "Rater2", r3: "Rater3" });
    }
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ panelval: event.target.value });
  }
  handleChangeHR(event) {
    this.setState({ hr: event.target.value });
  }

  handleChangeFinalScore(event) {
    this.setState({ finalScore: event.target.value });
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("A name was submitted: " + this.state.panelval);
    this.setState({ justLoaded: false });
    this.getRaterList(raterNameList => {
      this.getRaterName(raterNameList);
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.justLoaded) {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label> Consensus Panel Name: {this.state.panelval} </label>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <td className="matchsizing">Applicant Name</td>
                    <td className="scorebox">{this.state.r1}</td>
                    <td className="scorebox">{this.state.r2}</td>
                    <td className="scorebox">{this.state.r3}</td>
                    <td className="finalscorebox">Final Score</td>
                    <td className="finalscorebox">Advance?</td>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <table>
                  {this.state.raterNameList.map((ra, i) => (
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="matchsizing">
                          {i}: {ra.applicantname}{" "}
                        </td>
                        <td className="scorebox">{ra.rater1score}</td>
                        <td className="scorebox">{ra.rater2score}</td>
                        <td className="scorebox">{ra.rater3score}</td>
                        <td className="scorebox">
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            name="finalScore"
                            value={ra.finalscore}
                          />
                        </td>
                        <td className="scorebox">ra.advance</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">
                          <textarea
                            rows="5"
                            cols="136"
                            className="textarea"
                            placeholder="Enter details here..."
                          />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  ))}
                </table>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="9">
                  <label>Human Resources Representative: </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.hr}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeHR}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Panel Name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.panelval}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button type="button" value="get Panel" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            {" "}
            get Panel{" "}
          </button>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Consensus;
```

```
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("A name was submitted: " + this.state.panelval);
    this.setState({ justLoaded: false });
    this.getRaterList() // <- here we made async call
    this.getRaterName() // <- this function will called before we get back data
}
```

Explanation 
You were making async call and before that response comes back you started reading state and that is not yet updated because you api call is in progress state.

What i did is added one callback function and once app call is done we will set state and call callback function so that getRaterName state will be called once we got the data.

also i've just refined 
`getRaterName` we don't need to call `setState` function for each object we can update state in one shot.

you can refine other `setState` same way.

Also instead of setting `raterName` after setting `raterNameList` you can do this as well

```
  getRaterList = () => {
    var fetchquery="./api/consensustable?panelName=" + this.state.panelval
    console.log ("Hello" + fetchquery)
    console.log ("mounted =" + this.state.justLoaded)
    fetch(fetchquery)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then (raterNameList =>{
         this.setState({
            raterNameList, 
            r1: raterNameList[0] ? raterNameList[0].rater1name: "Rater1",
            r2: raterNameList[0] ? raterNameList[0].rater2name: "Rater2",
            r3: raterNameList[0] ? raterNameList[0].rater3name: "Rater3"
         })
    })
  };
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("A name was submitted: " + this.state.panelval);
    this.setState({ justLoaded: false });
    this.getRaterList();
  }
```

Comment: @Sharma: Super awesome.  Thanks Sharma.  Yes, it works .  Now I learned about async calls and how to write it so that one is called after another!  Thanks a million

Comment: anytime happy to help.